# CSS the ":visited :hover"-madness

Tags: html, css

I have an `ul`, linked list elements, and none-linked `li`.

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
        <li>second_level</li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

What I'm trying to do is make EVERYTHING within this `ul`, get these attributes (doesn't matter if the link was visited or not)

```
color:#fff; background-color:#ff6600;
```

when **hovering**.
(When nothing happens, its `color:#ff6600; background-color:#fff;`.)

So far I have:

```
li, a {
  transition:all 1000ms; -webkit-transition:all 1000ms;
  -moz-transition:all 1000ms; -ms-transition:all 1000ms;
  -o-transition:all 1000ms;
}

nav ul li:hover a:visited, nav ul li:hover,
nav ul li a:hover a:visited, nav ul li a:hover {
  color:#fff; background-color:#ff6600;
}
```

It works... kinda... the "animation" is too fast on the linked `li`'s; on the none-linked `li` ("`second_level`") it works fine.

Any tips on how to get the "animation" smooth on every item? I'm assuming that the attributes cancel each other, but cant find it.

Comment: wht u expect the animation so fast ?

Comment: I don't get the problem .. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsb5j7b6/) and every element is as smooth as each other

Comment: you mean the second `ul` all `li` changes its color

Comment: Well it gets same effect on all linked and non-linked, but still if there is some issue, then try applying individual hover effect to li and a.

Comment: @tektiv not for me. The color of the text changes faster on linked items then on none-linked items.

Comment: For me it works like this:


**nav ul li:hover {color:#fff; background-color:#ff6600;}

nav ul li:hover a {color:#fff;}**

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This could be a quirk due to multiple declaration.

Try to simplify your css:

```css
nav ul li:hover
{color:#fff; background-color:#ff6600;}
```

Works fine, [look here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsb5j7b6/2/).

Comment: @tektiv Please keep your language professional on SO.

Comment: I guess you wrote the wrong link : `http://nav%20ul%20li:hover%20%7Bcolor:#fff;%20background-color:#ff6600;%7D`